# Alterar apenas um checkbox

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic3

Como faço para mudar apenas o checkbox que estou clicando?

```js
checked:boolean=false;
ck() {
    if(this.checked === false){
      this.checked=true;
    }else{
      this.checked=false;
    }
```

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label  class="title" [class.title-service-check]="checked">item 01 <span class="box-service-price">R$ 80,00</span></ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox color="green" (click)="ck()"></ion-checkbox>      
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label class="title" [class.title-service-check]="checked">item 02 <span>R$ 80,00</span></ion-label>        
  <ion-checkbox color="green" (click)="ck()"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Eu não uso Ionic, não sei se aqui tem como executar ionic, mas você já tentou colocar `this` dentro de `ck()`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Voce precisa de uma variavel checked com outro nome claro pra cada checkbox. Voce tbm nao precisa de uma funcao pra essa logica. Voce pode fazer assim:

```
<ion-checkbox color="green" (click)="checked=!checked"></ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: tentei e não foi, como exatamente eu devo setar essa variavel?